# How can I change this to have it stop printing the else statement on top and bottom?

Tags: java, hierarchy, encapsulation

```
public double getPrice() {
    if(size.equals("S")) {
        price = 19.99;
    }
    else if(size.equals("M")) {
        price = 29.99;
    }
    else if(size.equals("L")) {
        price = 39.99;
    }
    return price;
}
```

}

```
public double getPrice() {
    
    
    if(this.Citrus) {
        return super.getPrice() + 5.99;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("That is not a citrus fruit your price is: " + super.getPrice());
        return super.getPrice();
```

Was wondering why my getPrice() was printing in two spaces, but I managed to figure it out.

Comment: You should remove `String.format("%.2f",getPrice());` - that doesn't actually use the formatted `String`, and it invokes `getPrice` a second time (you invoke it the first time with the `toString` method). Today would be a great day to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your getPrice() and Display() methods and include this code in your FruitSnack Class

small edit you don't need the setter. Instead update the price in getPrice() method.

```
private double price
//public void setPrice(double price){
    //this.price = super.getPrice() + 5.99;
//}

public double getPrice() {
    return super.getPrice() + 5.99;    
}

public void display() {
    if (! this.Citrus)
        System.out.println("That is not a citrus fruit your price 
        is:\n" + super.getPrice());
    else
        System.out.println(getPrice());
}
```